# Searching for simple but secure web-app to store a phone contact list for a group of people

Tags: web-apps, privacy, contact-manager

I'm looking for a good web-app to **store phone numbers and names of a group membership list**.

**"Good" means**:

- only members should be able to access the list (every member should be able to login via his own password)
- the list should be stored relatively safe
- every member should be able to see all other members and phone numbers after login
- every member should be able to insert, edit and delete only his own phone number and name
- should be easy to handle - as the members are not computer scientists :-)

Are there any good solutions out there for such specs?

Pricing should be not more than 10$ per month...

Comment: If you don't mind me saying so, but the requirements are a bit contradictionary. The combination of `gratis` and `SaaS` usually means you pay with your data (the provider must make a living as well). So "only members should be able to access…" is a bit illusory. Which means you'll need to compromise – either on the end of privacy, or payment. There *might* be exceptions to that rule, so best luck!